# MySQL Rows Disappearing (Mysteriously)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, innodb

I have 3 tables A, B and C which are directly linked and should contain the same number of rows, the rows for each table being created together.

I've recently noticed that after creating 1000 rows for test purposes (rows are definitely inserted, no transactions, system stable), and without any application activity, there seem to be rows missing.  A random amount of rows (0-50) from each table (e.g -30, -24, -7 which vary) seem to be missing after several hours of inactivity.

This has happened several times, and at first I didn't notice, but now I am positive. There is no code with anything such as `DELETE FROM table(A/B/C)`, so I have my doubts about a coding bug doing this.

I am using phpMyAdmin when I notice the missing rows, and a direct CLI query confirms this. I am certain I am not accidentally deleting the rows through the GUI.  Also, this is on a local test environment, so no (hopefully) public access.

Is there something in MySQL (a limitation setting) that could be causing this?  These are not unusual tables or rows, 10 columns each, `CHAR`/`INT`/`ETC`. types, 250kb each total each table.

Would a binary log file show which rows are being deleted and when and by whom?  Any special considerations for configuring the logging?

- Language is PHP, MySQL is InnoDB, WAMP, Windows, viewed through phpMyAdmin

Comment: Magic doesn't exist. Try do same things in `mysql` client.

Comment: I'll stop believing in magic when I fix this bug. Not sure what you mean to have me do...

Comment: Do your deletion or whatever stuff in console client. Check results. Make sure it's not magic

Comment: Can we see your code that creates the rows?

Comment: "direct CLI query confirms this". I hope you mean `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tablename`. Table row count reported by server (e.g. `SHOW TABLE STATUS`) is approximate for InnoDB tables. You need to clarify how you verify that rows are missing.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro, this was the problem.  But Steini got to it first.  Thank you for your help.  Hope this wasn't too newbie.

Comment: Please consider editing your question and adding the information I asked for, so it can be useful for other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using phpMyAdmin.

The preview of a table gives a estimated row count, not the actual one if you have alot of rows in your table.

Try

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableB;
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableC;
```

and see if there is really a different row count.

Otherwise, do you have any triggers set? Or any integrity issue with innoDB?

Comment: Thank you very much, no more magic. I'm glad good people like you are up this late. In my defense: I did notice the tilda (approximate) symbol next to the row count which made me wonder.  I was also using SHOW TABLE STATUS to confirm phpMyAdmin, which I didn't know was also an approximation. Happen to know after how many rows it starts approximating, and how often it is updated?

Comment: Its not that late here, just had lunch here. Glad that it could help you. Some years ago this issue made me puzzled aswell. And you cannot really know if noone tells you~ It starts approximating after dont know 5k rows or so, I dont remember the value but it does that only after plenty of rows are inside the table this is correct. Just watch for the "~" sign, if its there do a count.

Answer (score 1):

*Posted on behalf of the OP:*

Steini's answer was correct.  I had never worked with a 1000 row table and assumed MySQL would keep an internal row count on its own.  I also thought `SHOW TABLE STATUS` would give me an accurate count, but this (I am guessing) is also what phpMyAdmin uses to render its main page. It seemed strange that tables with the same number of rows would display different approximations, so I have no idea when and how often the approximations are updated. Most of this is available in the "Limits On InnoDB Tables" section of the MySQL reference manual.

SOLUTION: Use `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;` when retrieving an accurate row count, before querying StackOverflow with questions about magic and missing records.  Also read every single line in the manual.